# Thymeleaf button call url with parameters in new tab

Tags: button, thymeleaf, href

How can I create a button in thymeleaf to act as a link and opens in a new tab with some given parameters?

I tried this one but now works:

```
<button th:onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/location/' + ${id})"> GO</button>
```

It does not work when I'm using variables (`${id}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using bootstrap, I would represent the button like this.

```
<button
    th:data-url="@{https://www.google.com/location/{id}(id=${id})}"
    onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('data-url'))">GO</button>
```

Note: I'm using `onclick` and not `th:onclick`.

If you are using bootstrap, you can style the link as a button as in the other answer, and just use `th:href`.

```
<a class="btn" th:href="@{https://www.google.com/location/{id}(id=${id})}" target="_blank">GO</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below. bootstrap will help your anchor tag look like a button.

```
<a class="btn" th:href="@{/url/{id}(id=${id})}" target="_blank">GO</a>
```